# Persist custom registration information with Profile API

Tags: asp.net

I've seen examples of producing a custom registration control which persists its information with some extra fields (or a table depending on the problem) in the corresponding Sql Server.

It's also said that there is a way to do the same thing with the Profile API (persist custom info in a registration control). Is there a walkthrough for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link from MSDN [Storing User Information with ASP.NET 2.0 Profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379605.aspx)

You'll also need to know how to [Create the Application Services Database for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx)